# Do I have to list all the fields in my class or just the ones related to the stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, api, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-6.0

This is my first time creating a RESTful Web API ever. I'm using VS 2022 with .NET Core 6.

I'm inserting records into an existing table using an existing stored procedure. The table has 40+ columns, but the stored procedure only needs 14 columns.

For my model, do I need to define all 40+ columns, or just the ones I need for the stored procedure? The sample tutorials I found had matching column counts between the table and the stored procedure.

I've just started the design of my class.

Comment: Why would you make the client (caller) of the API provide something that the API won't use?

Comment: "I need you to give me a 'Status'. I'm not going to use it. The record's Status needs to be 'New' because it's a new record, but give it to me anyway because it's a column in the table."

Comment: You only need to declare the parameters that the stored procedure requires.